# Deep linking issue with flexslider

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, flexslider

I'm using flexslider for showing custom post type posts. I've managed to get the deep linking to work by adding the post id to each li element and using this to update the url with that id when clicking previous/next.

However I can't get this new link to work when it's pulled up in the browser. The goal is to use this url for sharing on facebook for example. When someone clicks the url it should go to that specific slide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $flexslider = $('.flexslider');     
                $flexslider.flexslider({
before:function (slider) {
          // get the ID of the slide we are animating to
          id = slider.slides[slider.animatingTo].id 
          // set the URL path to #slideID     
          history.pushState(null, null, "#" + id);
          },
                animation: "fade",
                                touch: false,
                                slideshow: false,
                manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
                useCSS: false /* Chrome fix*/               
});
});

<section id="slider">
      <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'juweel','orderby' => 'rand')); if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <li data-thumb="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="slide" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </li>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I know I can get the current location hash by using

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

But I have no clue how to check if the value matches the id of one of my slides and make it go there

Comment: _“However I can't get this new link to work when it's pulled up in the browser”_ - what have you _tried_ to make it work then? I don’t see anything in that regard. Are you unsure where to start? Well by checking the current location hash when the page loads, and then checking if that value matches the ID of one of your slides …

Comment: as mentioned by @04FS once you get your target slide ID you will be able to add an active statement to it wich should make it open first.